# Using renderer with alpha: true doesn't clear in Firefox

Tags: firefox, three.js

I find that using the renderer with alpha: true in Three.js doesn't clear the canvas correctly in Firefox. Is this an issue (is there a workaround) or am I missing a step?

To see the problem use var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true }); in the code from http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene and the cube becomes a blob.

Edit: Live code at: http://webglworkshop.com/Leeds/TULIPS/TestSetup/Test_Threejs-IE.html

**WARNING: It *may* flicker so badly that it causes a seizure!**

Answer (score 0):

The `.setClearColor()` method is for clearing the canvas. The second value is the alpha by which you want to clear ([0-1] range).